# Bank deposit account

Tags: bank-account

Question: Tom puts $10,000 into a bank account that pays an annual effective interest rate of 4% for ten years. 
If a withdrawal is made during the first five and one-half years, a penalty of 5% of the withdrawal amount is made.
Tom withdrawals K dollars at the end of each of 4, 5, 6 and 7 years. The balance in the account at the end of year 10 is $10,000. 
Calculate K

Part of the calculations: 
If no withdrawals than total amount is 10K(1.04)^10 =$14802.42

$14802.42-$10000 = $4802.20 has been withdrawn

Withdrawals = $4802.20 = x(1.05) + x(1.05) + x + x

I know this is wrong, but how far wrong?

Comment: A homework problem?

Comment: Each withdrawal reduces future interest as well, so $4,802.20 is irrelevant.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula I came up with:

```
((((10000 x 1.04^4 - 1.05K) x 1.04 - 1.05K) x 1.04 - K) x 1.04 - K) x 1.04^3 = 10000
```

Solve for K.

Comment: The important question now is: do you know **why** I derived *this* equation?

Comment: Simultaneous equation. Observing the past into the future.

Comment: @Mark was I supposed to use simultaneous equations?  :(  I started at "year 0" and just followed the parameters set by the problem: four years of growth, then a year of growth and a deduction (including 5% penalty), then two more years like that, then three final years of growth.

Comment: Obviously not. There is no equation to the right. But those brackets get me everytime. Thank you.